# Necessary and sufficient conditions with single "if"

Tags: logic, solution-verification

> Before starting your undergraduate program, you decide to make sure you choose the
>   exact program that you will need to get your dream job at Black Mesa Research Facilities.
>   You visit them during an open day, and ask one of the Human Resource ocers about
>   career opportunities at Black Mesa. The ocer tells you that you can get a job in Black
>   Mesa only if you major in Mathematics or Physics, get at least a B average, with at
>   least two courses in Computer Programming. Taking this advice to heart, you major in
>   Physics, get a B+ average, and take three courses in computer programming. You then
>   apply to Black Mesa, and are rejected without interview. Could you claim that the HR
>   director lied to you? Justify your answer.

Here's my solution.

The director mentions that one gets a job at Black Mesa only if he satisfies the above criteria. This means that the above criteria form a set of necessary conditions for a job at Black Mesa but are not sufficient in and of themselves.

The director did not lie, because although I fulfilled all the criteria, I did not fulfill all the sufficient criteria. I only fulfilled necessary criteria. So, a job was not guaranteed.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Is this personal?

Comment: I think it is indeed personal for the lecturer who set this question :-)

Comment: @kuttakikore Ahaha!

Comment: what does a university undergraduate say? "would you like to supersize those fries?"

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct: the director did not lie to you, in fact he just told you the **necessary criteria** for getting the job at Black Mesa, omitting the **sufficient** ones.